# Use <c:forEach> with HashMap

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have a java class that sets an servlet attribute to a HashMap object:

```
request.setAttribute("types", da.getSecurityTypes());
```

where `request` is an HttpServletRequest Object, and `da.getSecurityTypes()` returns a HashMap Object.

Is there a way to go through the HashMap collection using c:foreach or some other JSTL tags?

I was thinking:

```
 <c:forEach var="type" items="${types}">
                 ...
     </c:forEach>
```

Or if it can't be done, how would one make a custom tag to process this?

Resorting to Java code in my JSP page is be my last resort and I'd like to know if this is possible with JSTL.

Thanks,
Jonas.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Yes, this is perfectly acceptable.

When you use `<c:forEach>` to iterate over a `Map`, each item in the iteration is an instance of `Map.Entry`. So given your example:

```
<c:forEach var="type" items="${types}">
   Key is ${type.key}
   Value is ${type.value}
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: One thing that I found out the hard way is that you cannot reuse the same variable in a second `<c:foreach>` loop. You need to provide a different name.

Answer (score 7):

It works, you'll have `type.key` and `type.value` to play with in the loop.