# table inside a column

Tags: html, jsp, jstl, html-table

I have this sample table in [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/23Lx6/) how my table should look like

The second column can have more than one row that should coincide with the original columns. I am very confused how to achieve this using `jstl <c:forEach>`

This is the code I have written which prints everything in the same row because i don't have any break statements for the inner `foreach` but I want something similar to what I have in jsfiddle

```
<c:forEach items="${abc.bcd }" var="abc">
<tr>
<td align="center"><c:out value="${abc.interval }" /></td>
<td><c:out value="${abc.operation}" /></td>
<td>
<c:forEach items="${abc.parts.info}" var="info">
<c:out value="${info.number}" />
<c:out value="${info.quantity}" />
<c:out value="${info.name}" />
</c:forEach>                        
</td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dunno how to detail the specs of how HTML based tables work, but the overall is rows within a single column isn't how it was developed to work. As the ration of rows with columns need to balance out in a matter of speaking.

If you have a column where you need the appearance of rows, your best bet it to place a new table within that column and build out the appearance of said rows within it

example:

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <td>
       <table>
         <tr>
           <td>Info</td>
           <td>Info</td>
           <td>Info</td>
         </tr>
       </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This one will put a table in the column. But the inner table columns woudn't align with the outer table. I want the inner table columns aligned with the outer table

Answer (score 0):

Looking at what you have constructed so far, it looks like you have a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) at `abc.parts.info`. If you have an ordered map, like a [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html), you could [iterate trough the map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2210907/use-cforeach-with-hashmap):

```
<c:forEach items="${abc.bcd}" var="abc">
  <tr>
    <td align="center"><c:out value="${abc.interval}" /></td>
    <td><c:out value="${abc.operation}" /></td>
    <c:forEach items="${abc.parts.info}" var="info">
      <td><c:out value="${info.value}" /></td>
    </c:forEach>                        
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

If you have an unordered map, like a [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), you could just access values in your map using EL (assuming your keys are strings):

```
<c:forEach items="${abc.bcd}" var="abc">
  <tr>
    <td align="center"><c:out value="${abc.interval}" /></td>
    <td><c:out value="${abc.operation}" /></td>
    <td><c:out value="${abc.parts.info['number']}" /></td>
    <td><c:out value="${abc.parts.info['quantity']}" /></td>
    <td><c:out value="${abc.parts.info['name']}" /></td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
```