# I iterate Map<k,y> in jsp use c:foreach tag then get nothing?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm newer in java. I need to iterate the news type in jsp page. I use `<c:foreach>` to do than in jsp page. In javaee Eclipse IDE I create a servlet to respose to jsp page. And create a *newstype* class in java to get and set newsid and newsname. Then in jsp loop newsid and newsname, code like:

```
<ul>
    <c:forEach var="type" items="${types}">
        <li><a href="#"><c:out value="${type.typeName}"/></a></li>
    </c:forEach>
</ul>
```

There is the servlet code:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        newsservice ns = new newsservice();

        Map<Integer,String> types = ns.getNewsType();
        request.setAttribute("types",types);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
```

But open jsp page in chrome I got nothing. I'm concerned I'm do something wrong connect servlet and jsp, and miss something in code. Please somebody finger out.
I'm sure import the taglib:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

This is the snapshot:
[newspage project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REa9x.png)

Comment: You should read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835683/how-to-loop-through-a-hashmap-in-jsp

Comment: `System.out.println(types.size());` try to print the size of the Map and make sure that you are getting items in your map or its just empty!

Comment: @Muhammad year I'm sure got the map

Answer (score 0):

The expression type.typeName cannot be called on a Map (checkout the map API for methods you can call). You can loop over a Map however and get it's key and value.

Looks a lot like: [Use <c:forEach> with HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2210907/use-cforeach-with-hashmap#2210951)

Comment: I'm tried 'type.value', but the result is the same.

Comment: What result exactly? Can you post the generated html that is sent to the browser?

Comment: And have you verified that types contains items at all?
- add break point in doGet method right after you populate the items

Comment: I posted the code after the question. See snapshots. And I already debug the servlet doget method. It's totally fine . But I finally run in  the servlet can get the result fine and run in Jsp page can't get the result . So I confused. Maybe I need to read more documents about that?